# Kendo Scatter Chart - Different background colors for different areas

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, scatter-plot, kendo-chart

Consider the Kendo scatter chart [HERE](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scatter-charts/index) in the telerik demos. What I want is to visually separate the chart area with some background colors. As I know Kendo itself doesn't facilitate such configuration.

I'm tring to solve it within the Kendo. I guess it can be done through svg drawings. But I've never done it before. If it's really impossible is there any way to do it or is there any other scatter chart to fulfill this requirement.(saw somewhat similar thing in google charts)

I'm including the expected result as below. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I came up with [this code](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/charts/how-to/draw-on-scatter-plots) . It does the exact thing what I want. This is the solution.